# Angular 2: Input variable in Component does not update once called

Tags: angular, components

Hello people of StackOverflow!

I am having some trouble with my code. As you can see, I want to be able to call a row with a set width (bootstrap format), as I don't want to type the class every time.

So I thought of a way which is the following:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'content',
    template: ` <div class="row">
                    <div [ngClass]="contentClass" 
                         id="content" 
                         [ngStyle]="{ 'color': 'black', 'font-size': '20px' }">
                    <ng-content></ng-content>
                    </div>
                </div>`,
    styleUrls: ['content.stylesheet.css']
})

export class ContentComponent {
    @Input() rowWidth = "12";
    contentClass=(("col-lg-" + this.rowWidth)+(" col-sm-" + this.rowWidth)+(" col-xs-" + this.rowWidth));
}
```

But once I call the component from another component, it's not working the way I want.

```
<banner bannerHeight="300px"></banner>   <!-- This works -->
<content rowWidth="6"></content>         <!-- This doesn't -->
```

If I used for example

```
<content [ngStyle]="{'color': 'black'}"></content>
```

the operation succeeds. The directives and imports are set correctly in the parent component.

So here is my question: How do I make it work the way I want it to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't work (the way you want, i assume you mean that your `contentClass` has a `rowWidth` of `12`) because your assignment to `contentClass` is made before the template is actually initialized.

You have to implement `OnInit` and use `ngOnInit` to set the `contentClass` with the assignment to your `rowWidth` input:

```
export class ContentComponent implements OnInit{
    @Input() rowWidth = 12;
    contentClass:string;

    ngOnInit():any {
        this.contentClass = (("col-lg-" + this.rowWidth)+(" col-sm-" + this.rowWidth)+(" col-xs-" + this.rowWidth));
    }
}
```

With `<content [rowWidth]="6"></content>` your element will then have `col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6` instead of `12` set as its css classes.

Comment: That did the trick! I totally forgot about the lifecycle hooks.. rookie mistake. So as this did the trick for the contentClass, would it be best practice to implement such a thing for every input variable or only when there is processing time spent on it (for example a calculation or concatenation)?

Comment: Well, if you want to use your input at time of initialization, then yes (which you want most of the time) you need a lifecycle hook.